# ElasticSearch post_filter Java API issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to use the ElasticSearch Java APIs to do a query-string-query and then restrict the results by a date range based on a field in the result set.  When I test it out using Kibana I get 77 hits but when I try to do the same thing using the Java APIs I get '0' hits.

Here is the query as written in Kibana:

```
GET /enyo_cad/_search
{
  "from": 0, "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "smith",
      "lenient": true
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "range": {
      "cadIncident.dateTimeReceived": {
        "gte": "2014-01-01T00:00:00",
        "lte": "2016-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": false
  },
  "sort": [
        { "cadIncident.dateTimeReceived":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
}
```

And here is my Java code:

```
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(searchString)
                                                    .lenient(Boolean.TRUE)
                                                    .analyzeWildcard(Boolean.TRUE)
                                                    );
        searchSourceBuilder.from(fromHit);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(pageSize);
        if (startDate != null && endDate != null) {
            String dtName = getDateTimeAttributeName(appList, radarManager);

            searchSourceBuilder.postFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(dtName)
                                                        .gte(startDate)
                                                        .lte(endDate));
        }

    //  This section will sort the results IF there is only 1 application module selected OTHERWISE default revelvance score based sorting will continue.
        if (dateSort && appList.size() == 1) {
            searchSourceBuilder.sort(getDateTimeAttributeName(appList, radarManager), SortOrder.DESC);
            searchSourceBuilder.sort("_score", SortOrder.DESC);
        }

        HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder(); 
        HighlightBuilder.Field highlightFields = new HighlightBuilder.Field("*"); 
        highlightFields.highlighterType("unified");  //highlighter type unified is default https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html
        highlightBuilder.field(highlightFields);  
        searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder);

        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder); 
        searchRequest.indices(indexFilter);



        searchResponse = restClient.search(searchRequest, requestOptions);

        SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: What is pageSize and fromHit?

Comment: It is a method for returning a page worth of hits and viewing 'next page' of a varying size.

Comment: the next line "String dtName = getDateTimeAttributeName(appList, radarManager)" gets the field name for the index that is to be queried for a date range.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..  Sorry for the post when it was just a simple missing pair of parentheses .. should have been

if (dateSort && (appList.size() == 1)) {